How to know the process status in multiprocessing in the target function?
In the multiprocessing how can I know the status(like its running,killed) of current process and other process ?
My scenario is 2 process are running
process_run = multiprocessing.Process(target=run, name="run")
process_read = multiprocessing.Process(target=read_process, name="read_process")
process_run.start()
process_read.start()
processes = [process_run,process_read]

for p in processes:
    p.join()



Here I want to kill process_read once process_run execution is done.
process_read psudo code looks something like this:
def read_process():
    while True:
        #read the data and print in the terminal
        time.sleep(20)


Here I am using while True so this process will not be terminated (not a good way I know). So here I want the stopping condition like once other process is done kill this process.
Can somebody help ?

There's a lot of missing info here.  How are these processes related?  Are they sharing info through a queue?  Typically a process is done when a its task is finished...what is keeping these things alive to the extent that you need to terminate them?

Use a multiprocessing.Event to signal the other process.
Demo:
import multiprocessing as mp
import time

def process1(stop_event):           # Each process receives the event
    while not stop_event.is_set():  # Run while event is not set
        print('process1')
        time.sleep(.1)
    print('process1: stop')

def process2(stop_event):           # Each process receives the event
    for i in range(5):
        print('process2:', i)
        time.sleep(.1)
    print('process2: done')
    stop_event.set()                # Signal other process to stop

if __name__ == '__main__':
    funcs = process1, process2
    stop_event = mp.Event()  # Create event and send to each process
    processes = [mp.Process(target=func, args=(stop_event,)) for func in funcs]
    for p in processes:
        p.start()
    for p in processes:
        p.join()

Output:
process1
process2: 0
process1
process2: 1
process1
process2: 2
process1
process2: 3
process1
process2: 4
process1
process2: done
process1: stop


You can utilize a shared memory resource that can be utilized by both of your processes and which will work as a switch to exit one of your processes.
So in your case if you want process_read to stop on the signal of process_run, you can have a shared switch which will be set by process_run and for every while loop process_read will decide to continue or not based on this switch value.
Following can be a sample implementation:
# main program
shared_switch = multiprocessing.Value('b', 1)  # b represents `int` for python and `signed char` in C Type.
process_run = multiprocessing.Process(target=run, name="run", args=(shared_switch,))
process_read = multiprocessing.Process(target=read_process, name="read_process", args=(shared_switch,))
process_run.start()
process_read.start()
processes = [process_run,process_read]

for p in processes:
    p.join()

Read process:
# read process
def read_process(shared_switch):
    while shared_switch.value:
        #read the data and print in the terminal
        time.sleep(20)

Run process:
# run process
def run(shared_switch):
    # does some work here
    shared_switch.value = 0

Here, a shared switch relies in a shared memory space for all the processes and is thread-safe.
You can read more about it here: Shared memory
To know more about b used in Value object, go here: ctypes
